# MS Access Form and Tables

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a specific question regarding the utilization of three tables in a database.  Table 1 is called Personnel, and lists the names of the staff.

Tables 2 and 3 are identical, just listing two different types of overtime (long and short), along with the hours of the OT, Date of the OT, and Assigned to/Picked fields that are empty.

Here is the idea, I just dont know how to implement it.  I would like to create a form for people to enter their OT picks, then automatically move to the next person on the list.  So Rich Riphon, as an example, would be up first, would click on the link I would send, and a form would open up, showing his name, populated by the first table, and showing two drop down menus, populated from the Long OT and Short OT tables.  He would select one from each (or None, which would be a option) and Submit it.

The form action would be to place his name in the Assigned field for the OT he picked, and place a Yes in the Picked field.

When the next person in the list opens the form, it has moved down to number 2 on the Personnel list, Cheryl Peterson, and shows her the remaining OT selections (excluding those that have a Yes in the Picked column).

Any suggestions or comments or better ways to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an Access DB deployed on a network, with links sent via email?  Which version of Access?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think ms access would be able to (easily) kick off the process based on a hyperlink.  You may be able to do something by passing a macro name to a cmd prompt but it would take some mastery to get it working properly.  Could you instead create a login form to get the current user?  If you do that you don't really need to display the personnel list, just keep track of who has not yet responded to the OT request.  Essentially at that point all you would need on  your form is a listing of the available OT and a button that creates the assignment.  Also it may be easier (and a better design) to only have one table for the OT listings and add a column for the type of overtime (long/short).

Answer (score 0):

What if Cheryl isn't the 2nd person to get the form?  Your concept goes out the window.

Instead, I would keep a table of all user names, and their security level.  managers can see everything, individual users can only see their record.  This would be done by using a query behind the OT Picks form, and either filtering by the current user or not filtering at all.  I have done many of these types of "user control" databases and they all have worked well.

As for the actual OT tracking, I agree with Steve's post in that it should be done in one table  This would be the preferred method of a concept referred to as "normalizing data".  You really want to store as little data as possible to keep the size of your database down.  As an example, your Login table would have the following fields:

- UserID
- FirstName
- LastName
- SecurityLevel
- Address1
- Address2
- City
- State
- Phone
- Etc... (whatever relevant info pertains to that person)

Your OT table would look like this:

- UserID
- OTDate
- OTHours
- OTType
- Etc... (whatever else is relevant to OT)

You would then join those 2 tables on the UserID fields in both tables any time you needed to write a query to report OT hours or whatever.